# Matching strings, consider some characters are the same

Tags: objective-c, performance, search, character

please help me with this problem.

I want to check if the `targetString` match the `keyword` or not. Consider some character may different, but should still return true.

Example:

```
targetString = @"@ß<"
keyword = @"abc", @"∂B(", @"@Aß<"
result: all must return true.
```

(Matched.`targetString` and all `keyword` are the same.)

Consider me have an array, contains list of character set that can be the same:

```
NSArray *variants = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aA@∂", @"bBß", @"c©C<(", nil]
```

So that when matching, with this rule, it can match as the example above.

Here is what i've done so far (using recursion):

```
- (BOOL) test:(NSString*)aString include:(NSString*) keyWord doTrim:(BOOL)doTrim {
//    break recursion.
    if([aString length] < [keyWord length]) return false;

// First, loop through each keyword's character
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [keyWord length]; i++) {

// Get @"aA@∂", @"bBß", @"c©C<("  or only the character itself.
// like, if the keyword's character is A, return the string @"aA@∂". 
// If the character is not in the variants set, eg. P, return @"P"

        char c = [keyWord characterAtIndex:i];
        NSString *rs = [self variantsWithChar:c];

//       Check if rs (@"aA@∂" or @"P") contains aString[i] character           
        if([rs rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithCharacters:[aString characterAtIndex:i] length:1]].location == NSNotFound) {
//        If not the same char, remove first char in targetString (aString), recursion to match again.

            return [self test:[aString substringFromIndex:1] include:keyWord doTrim:NO];
        }
    }
 // If all match with keyword, return true.
    return true;
}

- (NSString *) variantsWithChar:(char) c {
    for (NSString *s in self.variants) {
        if ([s rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",c]].location != NSNotFound) {
            return s;
        }
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", c];
}
```

The main problem is, `variantsWithChar:` doesn't return the correct string. I don't know which datatype and which function should I use here. Please help.

For thou who know ruby, here's the example in ruby. It work super fine!

```
require 'test/unit/assertions'

include Test::Unit::Assertions

class String
  def matching?(keyword)
    length >= keyword.length && (keyword.chars.zip(chars).all? { |cs| variants(cs[0]).include?(cs[1]) } || slice(1, length - 1).matching?(keyword))
  end

  private

  VARIANTS = ["aA@∂", "bBß", "c©C<("]

  def variants(c)        
      VARIANTS.find { |cs| cs.include?(c) } || c        
  end
end

assert "abc".matching?("@ß<")
```

PS: The fact is, it's containt a japanese character set that sounds the same (like `あア`, `いイ`... for thou who know japanese)

PS 2: Please feel free to edit this Question, since my engrish is sooo bad. I may not tell all my thought.

PS 3: And, maybe some may comment about the performance. Like, search about 10,000 target words, with nearly 100 variants, each variant have at most 4 more same characters.

Comment: This seems like an unnecessarily complicated way to go about this.  Why not translate your target string into the same basis alphabet as the keyword then test for an exact match?

Comment: Well, in the future, when implement this code, I don't even know what the target string look like... How do I translate it?

Comment: char won't hold most of the characters you want to work with. Unichar is made for Unicode. So at some point you need to start with something. Then you can look at Identifying other words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while (a day) working on the code above, I finally get it through. But don't know about the performance. Someone comment and help me improve about performance, please. Thanks.

```
- (BOOL) test:(NSString*)aString include:(NSString*) keyWord doTrim:(BOOL)doTrim {
//    break recursion.
    if([aString length] < [keyWord length]) return false;

// First, loop through each keyword's character
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [keyWord length]; i++) {

// Get @"aA@∂", @"bBß", @"c©C<("  or only the character itself.
// like, if the keyword's character is A, return the string @"aA@∂". 
// If the character is not in the variants set, eg. P, return @"P"

    NSString* c = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [keyWord characterAtIndex:i]];
    NSString *rs = [self variantsWithChar:c];
    NSString *theTargetChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [aString characterAtIndex:i]];

//       Check if rs (@"aA@∂" or @"P") contains aString[i] character           
        if([rs rangeOfString:theTargetChar].location == NSNotFound) {
//        If not the same char, remove first char in targetString (aString), recursion to match again.
            return [self test:[aString substringFromIndex:1] include:keyWord doTrim:NO];
        }
    }
 // If all match with keyword, return true.
    return true;
}
```

If you remove all comment, it'll be pretty short...

////////////////////////////////////////

```
- (NSString *) variantsWithChar:(NSString *) c{
    for (NSString *s in self.variants) {
        if ([s rangeOfString:c].location != NSNotFound) {
            return s;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So first off, ignore comments about ASCII and stop using char. NSString and CFString use unichar

If what you really want to do is transpose hiragana and katakana you can do that with CFStringTransform()
It wraps the ICU libraries included in OS X and iOS. 
It makes it very simple. 
Search for that function and you will find examples of how to use it.

Comment: I tried unichar... [variantWithChar:] doesn't work. It return wrong char. Further, it's much more complicate than just hira and kana. Have you ever heard of `itaiji` ?

Comment: Itaiji variants might require special handling. Even font foundieries need to do special work for those

Answer (score -1):

You could try comparing ascii values of the japanese characters in the variants's each character's ascii value. These japanese characters aren't treated like usual characters or string. Hence, string functions like rangeOfString won't work on them.

to be more precise: have a look at the following code.
it will search for "∂" in the string "aA@∂"

```
NSString *string = @"aA@∂";

NSMutableSet *listOfAsciiValuesOfString = [self getListOfAsciiValuesForString:string]; //method definition given below

NSString *charToSearch = @"∂";

NSNumber *ascii = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[charToSearch characterAtIndex:0]];

int countBeforeAdding = [listOfAsciiValuesOfString count],countAfterAdding = 0;

[listOfAsciiValuesOfString addObject:ascii];

countAfterAdding = [listOfAsciiValuesOfString count];


if(countAfterAdding == countBeforeAdding){ //element found
    NSLog(@"element exists"); //return string
}else{
    NSLog(@"Doesnt exists"); //return char
}
```

===================================

```
-(NSMutableSet*)getListOfAsciiValuesForString:(NSString*)string{
    NSMutableSet *set = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    for(int i=0;i<[string length];i++){

        NSNumber *ascii = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[string characterAtIndex:i]];

        [set addObject:ascii];
    }

    return set;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more details? And, I believe that we will have to use hex code or unicode instead of ascii. Am I wrong?